# Develop an AC - equivalent circuit

Tags: transistors, amplifier, ac

The actual question is, "Develope the AC-equivalent circuit (**Using Hybrid-Pi model for transistor**), from which you can calculate the voltage gain, and the input and the output impedances"
[image]

We haven't been taught anything about **Hybrid-Pi model** yet, i tried going through my textbook and some youtube tutorial, but it was too broad before i could actually solve this circuit. I set capacitors to short circuit, and Vcc to 0v/ground. But the main problem is (transistor).

It would be really helpful, if i could get an explanation (**with figure**) about the **Hybrid-Pi model** of circuit above.

Comment: Let me google that for you, first hit was https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid-pi_model

Comment: If you need an explanation and detailed analysis, please read this: http://users.ece.gatech.edu/~alan/ECE3040/Lectures/Lecture20-BJT%20Small%20Signal%20Model.pdf

Comment: @RohatKılıç that gatech link is quite a thorough treatment. Recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hybrid-pi model of the transistor (for low frequencies) is this:
[image]

Now let's fit the block in the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnzlQf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$
r_\pi = \frac{V_T} {I_{B(DC)}} = \frac{\beta_{DC}} {g_m} \\
g_m = \frac{1}{r_e} \text{; } r_e = \frac{V_T}{I_{C(DC)}} \Rightarrow g_m = \frac{I_{C(DC)}}{V_T} \text{  ;} V_T\text {: Thermal voltage}\cong 26mV \text{ @ 24°C} \\
r_o = \frac{V_A + V_{CE}}{I_C} \cong \frac{V_A}{I_{C(DC)}} \text{; }V_A: \text{Early Voltage}
$$

Now you can calculate the gain \$ K_v \$ from \$ \frac{Vo}{Vin} \$.